# How to use custom routes in GIS Map on Anylogic?

Tags: anylogic

I am trying to create a seaport optimization model. I need to specify the path on sea route, and avoid the land route. I tried to randomly create the route on GIS Map, please refer to image

[image]

But when I run the model, they are using the route set by the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

There is no automated way to get sea routes. Either draw them yourself with `GISRoute`, use a shape-file or program a web-API call to some route provider (ordered by growing difficulty for you :))

Comment: Still a long to get there to develop that web-API. I am taking small steps